# Is quark-gluon plasma dense enough to have an event horizon with enough of it?

Tags: gravity, event-horizon, quark-gluon-plasma

I've taken a few cracks and figuring this out myself, as a novice, with the equations $r_s=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$ and $M = \frac{4}{3}\rho \pi r^3$ but I think I'm just spinning in circles.

Is quark-gluon plasma dense enough (at almost 1 GeV/fm$^3$) to be able to form an event horizon if you have enough of it?

---

To calculate using the formula given by my2cts, my challenge is now I think just getting the units right.

To get $c$ into fm / s, I can just multiply by $10^{13}$ I think.

Can I do that with $G$ too? Or does it need to be $(10^{13})^3$? Looks like $G \times 10^{45}$ should do it.

---

This is what I did:

```
import math

G = 6.6743e-11    #m^3 kg^−1 s^−2
c = 299792458     # m / s

pevfm = 1e9       # eV / fm^3

kg = 1.782e-36

pkgfm = pevfm * kg
pkgm = pkgfm * 1e45

rs = (3 * c**2 / (8 * math.pi * G * pkgm))**0.5
print(rs)
```

If QGP had a density of 1 billion eV per femtometer$^3$, I get 9497 m.

Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inserting your second formula into the first you get $$r_s = \sqrt{\frac{3c^2}{8\pi G \rho}}~.$$
This means that for any density, including that of quark-gluon plasma, a sphere of sufficiently large radius will be a black hole. Note that such a black hole is not stable against collapse.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm curious because of what my be implied if QGP can't be compressed down to zero. I updated my question with my progress on solving the formula you gave. I think I'm still just lost at the units of everything. Thanks for your help!